# How do I fetch my config API on my admin website to be use in my Signin Page?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, api

I have my own config that I set up on my admin website, so every change that I made there, will be reflected on my website.

I'm referring to API, but I don't want to hardcode the base URL, I want to make it flexible, how do I do it?

**This is my admin's page that consists of the config**
[image: This is my admin's page]

**This is my shop.service.ts**
[image: This is my service.ts]

**This is my getconfig() function**
as you can see, I don't want it to be hardcoded like this, instead, I wanna make it flexible based on the config on my admin website
[image: This is my getconfig function]

Comment: You want to know a custom URL before getting the custom URL so that you can get the custom URL? You can't chicken before you egg. You'd need a hard-coded *initial* URL to get [all] the config[s] from, and then load that config in for any further usage. Unless I'm not properly understanding your issue.

Comment: no, what you are saying is correct, and you're saying that I have to hard-coded the config URL, no other way right?

Comment: Pretty much. You can't get something from a url you don't already know. You could put up a really basic mini API that exists solely to serve configs, I guess? One single url you can hardcode to kick the app off...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no way, I just have to hard code it first.